# What happens if a user offers money for an answer?

Tags: discussion

I just bumped a question. The title was saying [WILL PAY CASH MONEY FOR THIS TO BE ANSWERED](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25045227/ios-receiving-remote-push-notifications-for-only-certain-view-controllers).

I edited the question eventually, it was approved and downvoted. Are there any enforcements for these kind of behaviours or is just editing to remove the bad part and downvote enough? Should I flag it for moderator attention?

Comment: Don't flag, you've already taken care of it. (You did miss a spot, though.)  If you think that the question is particular not useful, then downvote it.

Comment: That OP's name - not suspicious at all.

Comment: I like the super hi-tech modeling presentation - *white* legal pad and a Sharpie.

Comment: TAKE THE MONEY!

Comment: *Insert joke about how the only legitimate currency around here is rep.*

Comment: "WILL PAY 500 REP FOR THIS QUESTION TO BE ANSWERED!" Don't use that as a title. Seriously. Just set a bounty...though I have to admit, it would be really funny to see that as a bounty message...

Comment: Is there some rule against paying for answers? I don't know anything about this.

Comment: [SHUT UP AND TAKE MY MONEY!](http://procrasti-nation.eu/wp-content/uploads/Shut-up-and-take-my-money.jpg)

Comment: Answer the question and give out my bank account no. :)

Comment: @codeMagic No, I'll take The box :D

Comment: I will accept $25 no wait.. $13 and a bacon. Deal or no deal? :D

Comment: @LittleChild bacon works for me as well but not Canadian one.

Comment: Only if it's Bitcoin.

Comment: Hey, you should trade reputation for Bitcoins.

Comment: This question gave me an idea for a new site.

Comment: Wait, you guys *don't* get paid for answers? Huh.

Comment: @user3717756 welp that would defeat the purpose of rep, on what basis are you going to trust a user's reliability

Answer (score 60, accepted):

You can't really expect payment, despite the OP's promises, from answering a question, so at best these should be treated as noise and edited out.  If the OP really wants to reward answers, they can set up a bounty after 24 hours have elapsed for their question.

If a user is *habitually* offering monetary compensation for answers to their question, then (and only then) would I bring it to a moderator's attention.

Comment: I wasn't expecting :)

Comment: "You can't really expect payment, despite the OP's promises", how dare you! I just bought [a bridge in New York](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/George_C._Parker) and, even though I haven't received the title yet, the guy sounded nice and I'm excited to receive my new bridge

Comment: @codeMagic On the other hand if somebody offers to sell you the Tapan Zee Bridge for cheap, it might actually be real. Even so, don't take it, it's a lemon.

Comment: Hey, but... someone got cupcakes for answering a bounty question.

Comment: Maybe Stack Overflow should open a Bit Coin exchange ;) Treat the payment like a bounty. Skim some off the transaction and profit. It should make sites like Rent-A-Coder shudder...

Comment: You failed to consider one thing. What if I put my e-mail address in my bio, posted a great answer to a new user's question, and then found that the asker had gleaned the e-mail address from my bio and awarded me money for the answer (and the transaction was legitimate and not fraudulent)? What should I do in that case? (Say that the poster did not initially *offer to give money in the question*.)

Comment: You mean 48 hours, right?

Comment: @damryfbfnetsi, Let us know when that actually happens to you. Here on StackOverflow, we don't deal with hypothetical questions. http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

Comment: @StephanBranczyk But that question isn't a question proper; it's just side discussion. But in my opinion, it's better to take preemptive measures against possible scenarios rather than only taking action when it actually happens. But yes, I do want an answer.

Comment: "You can't really expect payment, despite the OP's promises" - actually I expect payment. Unsure about laws in other countries but I know Estonian law handles such public promise as official offer with terms and it can be accepted which means it becomes contract. And contracts can be enforced if needed.

Comment: But this website has US Laws as far as I know, so the Estonian laws won't be enforced will they? @TõnuSamuel

Comment: Laws have quite similar ideas, logic and goals everywhere. Just I happen to know some other country than one-and-only one. And yes, Estonian law can be applied if result of someone's action occurs in Estonia. For example I get not paid and I happen to make "contract" in Estonia.  Civil laws work this way quite everywhere. Criminal stuff is different.

Comment: If they pay upfront, why not.

Comment: @TõnuSamuel Are you actually trying to say you could "enforce" Estonia laws in a foreign country based on a deal made on a foreign countries website with a foreign person? For some reason i highly doubt it, but good luck with that...

Comment: @Happy:  As far as I know, there's no rule against it, but conversely, there's no enforcement of secure delivery, either.  They can promise you the cash, but no one is going to enforce that promise.  If it's put in a question, it's going to come across as a guarantee, which is why I believe that sort of declaration is nothing better than noise.

Comment: @james, you didn't get the point. If website is directed to world, then other countries may apply their laws. Even Google and Apple have to accept it. And yes, if I make the deal on this website, I can enforce law at least in court. I agree bailiff stuff is more difficult but still possible.

Answer (score 107):

I had someone offer me money to help once.  I suggested he just donate it to a charity of his choice.  He later followed up with me and said he donated it to the Raspberry Pi Foundation.  I think that was a good result for everyone.

Comment: How nice both of you, indeed it is good action to take.

Comment: I had similar situation and directed OP to SQL Fiddle donation button (it was an SQL question).

Answer (score 5):

It was a shame because I started answering the question before he edited it to include a title. - As you saw it was a comprehensive answer and therefore the question was quite correctly closed as `too broad`

I do not use this site because I am expecting something in return, but because I like helping people improve their codebase and knowledge. That said like `Gabe` suggested I did suggest that If he really did feel he had to pay some money, then their was a link in my profile to `The British Red Cross`. I wasn't sure if it was against the rules but It was a whole lot better than accepting money for my answer.