# Is it OK to downvote on pre-edited version of question?

Tags: discussion, voting

This is related to mohacs's question, *[What happens if a user offers money for an answer?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267263/what-happens-if-a-user-offers-money-for-an-answer)*.

The fellow's answer was edited to remove the offending offer. When I looked at the question this morning, it was at -12. Six hours later, it's at -27. I'm only aware of one question that's worse (a fellow who got into an editing war and was reverting edits to the tune of -100 or so).

I'm kind of surprised the question has received another 15 down votes. I don't believe there is anything offensive with the question now. (Personally, I was not offended with the original question considering how many people ask for the same without offering anything. Close it and move on).

Is it OK to vote based on pre-edited or former versions of a question or answer? Is it encouraged? (I would expect it to be discouraged).

Or is this another case of "they are your votes, you're free to use them how you like"?

In the case of "they are your votes", what purpose does it serve? The question was closed and the fellow was downvoted, so what benefits does the additional negative feedback provide? (I'm trying to understand the thinking).

I have a feeling its one of the reason Stack Overflow has such a poor reputation at times. See, for example, [Could we please be a bit nicer to new users?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/9953/173448)

Comment: Well. They *are* your votes, you're free to use them however you like except in a fraudulent manner. As for why that particular question got downvotes, only the cows know. Maybe it's the meta-effect (pile-on downvotes because the question got put into the limelight) or because it's lengthy, or too broad, or someone lost their keys, or oscillation, or...

Comment: see: [The “I Get It” Reputation Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/552/165773)

Answer (score 7):

While the right to upvote/downvote/ignore remains with the individuals in the community, I would like to remind you all that community is expected to evaluate the ***content***, not the ***people***.

If a particular individual's content is persistently low in quality, he will be banned. That's another issue.

So I think that we all should evaluate the post at hand, rather than history, even if it is the history of the same post. Then again, it's your right to vote.

Comment: *"Then again, it's your right to vote..."* - The effects are no different than serial voting or vote fraud. Should the site tolerate it because users want to mob vote? The users are clearly mishandling the question, and I'm not sure I'd dismiss it so easily.

Comment: it's just too hard to police, from a practical standpoint.  If we could remove the human element then SO would be perfect.