# What to do when OP offers payment for solution?

Tags: discussion, etiquette

I saw a question in which the OP requested help with responsive CSS, his code had many issues which I tried to outline in the comments, only to get a response from the OP offering me payment in exchange of a solution to his problems.

I am wondering what is the Stack Overflow policy regarding this matter?

Comment: Duplicate, but the present question has (in my opinion) better answers, so I'm not voting to close: [What happens if a user offers money for an answer?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267263/what-happens-if-a-user-offers-money-for-an-answer)

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom: Shouldn't then the other question be closed as duplicate of this one?

Comment: @honk - Yes, the other question(s) should be marked as duplicate so people get directed to the one with the best answers.

Comment: I've seen people point the OP to the [Jobs Site](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/) in the comments but I've only ever seen the OP actually go for that once (and that was on Meta).

Comment: What a great job idea! *Stack Overflow Answerer!*

Comment: I know the answer, but it will cost you.

Comment: I had such situation once and, since it was an SQL question, suggested to OP to make a donation to the author of SQL Fiddle.

Comment: // , @PM 77-1 Yeahhh, like that will ever happen.

Comment: @NathanBasanese As a matter of fact OP did tell me later that he indeed followed my suggestion.  So it could happen.

Comment: // , He might have been lying, of course, but my faith in humanity has gone up a tick.

Comment: Get him to pay in advance, or put it in escrow ;-)

Comment: TAKE THE MONEY! (quote by codeMagic) is still the best advice. But don't forget to post the solution then also here.

Comment: related: [Are job offers spam?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/276250/839601)

Answer (score 91, accepted):

Whatever you want to do offsite is your own business, but the community frowns on monetary bounties for questions.

If you see language like this in a question, feel free to edit it out to focus on the meat of the question. If it's in a comment, flag the comment as noise and we'll get rid of it.

I wouldn't recommend downvoting or closing a question just because this had it in it. Again, if editing that out leaves behind a good question, do so and judge the question on the result.

Comment: Agreed.  Using SO as a referral center to hire is maybe what the CV (or jobfinder) site is for.  But offering to pay per question is an interesting wrinkle on a site which already does it for free.  I guess it means the questioner *doesn't get it*, or at least doesn't understand how well it already works.

Comment: There's a lot of people having paypal links, links to Amazon wishlists and even codementor profile pages in their SO profile page.