# Is it OK to hire external freelancers to answer questions?

Tags: discussion

I've got a SO question that, unfortunately, hasn't yet been answered (this is rare!).

I'm considering trying to hire an **external freelancer** to help out by answering the question.

*(I would use a freelancing site like **UpWork** to find a developer with the appropriate skills and offer the job to them.)*

Is it acceptable to pay external freelancers to answer SO questions, if it comes to that?

Comment: Closely related: [*What to do when OP offers payment for solution?*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/316137/2751851)

Comment: You might not be able to place a bounty on the question, but *others* can, which is why you want to frame a question to make it as easy to understand and (in particular) as interesting as possible. Even if you don't get an answer, you'll likely attract decent chatter in your question's comment section, and if you do, you could always ask someone to help you with a bounty.

Comment: see also: [Are job offers spam?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/276250/839601)

Comment: You mention you'd request the paid work from another site. I'd say, as long as that's not against *that site's* rules it's fine - the request for someone to do the job as paid work is not on Stack Overflow. It would be nice if that person (or you) then posted the solution as an Answer, here. But If no one here could answer and you paid for it, that would be completely up to you.

Comment: ALL: I do not think this is a duplicate. The OP has stated the request for paid work would be posted *on another site*. Those questions all have to do with money being offered on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @CindyMeister I think you're right. I think people were excessively dismissive on this one.

Comment: @CindyMeister The answers are still the same, though.

Comment: @User1973 If you’re gonna pay people to solve your problems, why involve SO at all? This sounds like outsourcing with extra steps.

Comment: @DanBron It's not like I set out to pay someone in the first place. I posted on SO in hopes that someone here could help (usually this is the case). However, this time, I didn't get an answer that solved my problem (rare!). So I figured I'd try to find someone externally to help. And if I (or the freelancer) posts the answer on SO, then chances are it might help someone else too.

Comment: Sometimes it seems like people crucify honest and reasonable questions...as a hobby.

Comment: @User1973 I see the logic behind paying for the “seed” and seeing what else sprouts on SO. As for “crucifixion”, I understand where you’re coming from. All I can offer is that downvotes are meaningless here. Don’t let them sting. They just mean “this person disagrees”. That doesn’t mean they’re right (or that you’re right), just that there’s a debate. If you can allow yourself to take this grander view, it stops hurting. Honestly.

Comment: @DanBron. Well put. I feel slightly less bitter. Cheers.

Comment: \*[Upwork](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Upwork)

Answer (score 7):

There's a share button on every question (there was a banner too). You can use any method you are able to get your question answered. Now, we ask from you that whatever you do, you don't send spam and accept that anyone could post an answer to your question, but it may not be the answer we are looking for.